# Filter nested object javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, methods, filter

For Example we have obj

```
const obj {

    user: {
         firstName: 'ivan',
         lastName: 'Petrov',
         role: {
              roleID: '111',
              roleName: 'admin',
            },
       },
    user: {
         firstName: 'Vlad',
         lastName: 'Segeda',
         role: {
              roleID: '222',
              roleName: 'Moderator',
            },
       }

}
```

I need search and display data. I create this filter, where "data"- its object, "params" - its value from search/filter input .

```
export const filter = (data, params) => {
    const keys = data[0] ? Object.keys(data[0]) : [];
    return data.filter((item) => {
        return keys.some(key => item[key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(params.toLowerCase().toString()) !== -1)
    });
};
```

but this helper doesnt work properly. When I type in input Admin or Moderator. it returns nothing.

I dont know, maybe i should use forEach....

Help me please

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? Still couldn't understand your need

Answer (score 0):

I assume data is an object similar to obj, then data[0] is undefined because data is an object, not an array.

And if obj is an object, user as an object key is duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a recursive function that checks whether a user object values satisfy the input.

```
const checkNestedRecursive = (obj, params) => {
    let flag = false;
    for(let key in obj) {
        if(typeof key === 'object') flag = flag || checkNestedRecursive(key, params);
        if(!flag) 
            flag = flag || obj[key].toString()
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .indexOf(params.toLowerCase().toString()) !== -1
        if(flag) return flag;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Then you can filter your users:

```
users.filter(user => checkNestedRecursive(user, params));
```